# Running PyTest Tests in Pycharm

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm, pytest

I am working on writing tests for my python code. I explored unit tests and decided to use PyTest. I am using PyCharm for my IDE to run/debug my python code.

However, when I run the test file that I created, it does not output anything in the PyCharm output. I have read about similar issues [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002838580-Why-does-PyCharm-not-run-pytest-testing-for-my-application-). As a result, I went into the PyCharm preferences and changed the default testing from unit test to PyTest. However, this did not seem to fix the problem. I am a little unsure of how to get this to display the desired output. I imagine if I were to run this in the terminal the output would display properly. I am just having trouble seeing it in PyCharm.

Although it is not really relevant, the python code file I am testing is a simple definition of a function that computes the fibonacci sequence. The test file, aptly named, test_fib then tests it. Everything runs properly, but the traditional PyTest output (all tests passed etc.) is not displaying.

Any suggestions? I can add additional information or details if necessary.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have included a snapshot to illustrate more or less the expected output:

[image]

Comment: When you "run the test file," does it actually run as a PyTest configuration? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: It just outputs "Process finished with exit code 0" the normal PyCharm output.

Comment: It still sounds like it's not running as a PyTest configuration, just as a regular Python file. After you changed the default test runner, did you delete the old run configuration and recreate a new one?

Comment: Ah that might do the trick, not sure how exactly to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you've changed the default runner to pytest, per your reference, *new* "Configurations" should now use that setting.  However, old/existing ones will not.

**Change the Default test runner**

Assuming you've already done this, but for completeness sake:

1. Go to `File` > `Settings`
2. Go to `Tools` > `Integration Tools`
3. Under `Default test runner`, change it to `pytest`
4. Click `OK`

**Recreating a Configuration**

To **delete** an existing Configuration:

1. Go to `Run` > `Edit Configurations`. This should bring up the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog box.
2. Find and select the configuration you'd like to delete
3. Click the `-` icon on the upper-left corner of the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog box.
4. Click `OK` on the bottom-right corner of the dialog box.

To **create** a new Configuration:

1. Right-click on your pytest file
2. Select `Run 'pytest in <your pytest file name>...'`

**More information about Configurations**

These are my Configurations:

[image]

Notice:

- "export_order" is just a "Python" Configuration
- "pytest in auth_integration_test.py" is a "Python test" type of Configuration

When a pytest Configuration is run, it should look something like this:

[image]

**References**

JetBrains' PyCharm/Pytest help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pytest.html

**Side Note**

In addition, notice one of the comments in the link you provided suggests manually creating a pytest configuration.  That, technically, answers your question, too.